# add constructor to templated class

Tags: c++

I have a templated class holding a value. Is it possible to add a constructor to the class to allow implicit conversion like in the example below?

Or is there a better way to do this?

```
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class Value
{
  public:
    Value(const T& value) : m_value(value) { };
  private:
    T m_value;
};

// I thought adding something like this would do the trick but it does not work:
/*
template<>
class Value<std::string>
{
  public:
    Value(const char *sz) : m_value(sz) { };
}
*/

void f(const Value<std::string> &s)
{
}

int main()
{
  f(std::string("hello"));

  // I want to have this working:
  f("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `f(const Value<std::string>&)` with a string literal would require two user-defined conversions (`const char[]`==>`std::string`==>`Value<std::string>`) in order to match the function parameters, while the standard only allows one.
I see two possibilities to solve that: either overload the constructor or overload `f()`.

Assuming you're asking about the former because the latter isn't possible, there are several ways to overload the constructor.

You could exploit the fact that member functions of a class template are only compiled if they are invoked, and add a constructor that only compiles when `T` is of a certain type. Of course, if users of your template invoke it for other types, this will result in an error. 
However, instead of seeing a problem in this you could embrace it by making the constructor a member template:

```
template<typename U>
Value(const U& value) : m_value(value) { };
```

That way, whatever can be converted into `T` (as well as `T` itself, of course) is allowed for `U`.

Or you could specialize the class for `std::string`. Unfortunately, you would then have to specialize *the whole class* as there is no selective specialization of individual members. So in this case you might want to move all the code into a common (possibly `private` base class of `Value`, with the `Value` base template just defining constructors that forward to the base class' constructors, and a specialization `Value<std::string>` which adds another constructor taking `const char*`.

Comment: I also thought it was implicitly convertible but the compiler (g++) complains about it (invalid initialization of reference).

Comment: and no, the string is not a placeholder

Comment: @rve: I'm sorry, this was a brainfart of mine. I failed to see that you wanted to call `f()` with a C string. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. This is an explicit decision by the C++ designers. The reason is that the compiler would need to go hunting for possible conversions, and in general this would be an infinite hunt.

Sure, you think that `const char[]` ==> `std::string` ==> `Value<std::string>` is logical. But the compiler doesn't have `std::string`. It just has `const char[]` ==> ??? ==>`Value<std::string>`, and it would need to find a type in the middle. For instance, there might be a `class Foo` somewhere that has a `Foo::Foo(const char*)` constructor, and an `Foo::operator Value<std::string>() const`. That would work, too.

As you can see, there's nothing in either `const char[]` or `Value<std::string>` that points to Foo. Hence, the compiler would have to go on a blind hunt.

As the writer of `Value`, you do have a choice, though. You can inform the compiler that a `Value<std::string>` can be constructed from any type that std::string::string will accept:

```
template<typename T>
class Value
{
  public:
    Value(const T& value) : m_value(value) { };
    // Intentionally not "explicit"
    template<typename U> Value(const U& value) : m_value(value) { };
  private:
    T m_value;
};
```

Now, if you call `void f(const Value<std::string> &s)` as `f("hello")`, there's a single implicit conversion `Value<std::string>::Value<const char*>(const char* const&)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't add to the class like that, but you can specialize the entire class.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://www.ideone.com/PgTPL):

```
template<typename T>
class Value
{
  public:
    Value(const T& value) : m_value(value) { }
    Value(const char* a): m_value(a){} // add this
  private:
    T m_value;
};
```

Comment: @rve : My sole intention was to make your code free from compilation errors ;-)